# JSON through Services View- Authenticating through Parameters when accessing JSON through external app

Tags: 7, users, services

My Drupal site is generating JSON through Views. I am using Services for that.

It is something like this:-

```
http://www.asite.com/api/views/all-date.json
```

Now the problem is that I want to restrict anyone from writing that URL in the any browser and retrieving all data.

Do you think there is a way to authenticate it?

Probably, in my external app, when I am accessing the data, I can add parameters to it so that it can only send data when it has right authentication.

Something like this:-

```
http://www.asite.com/api/views/all-date.json/?username=me&password=mine
```

I'll be grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

There exit many ways of authentication through services module.

The easiest is to use session authentication by authenticating the user using his **username & password**, Then let the app send the cookie header in each request with the session id like **COOKIE: SESS_ID:SESS_name**.

Or use that module that seems matching your approach a lot [services_basic_auth](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_basic_auth)

Another way is to authenticate the app itself by letting the app get an access token using a secret app id and password created on the website.   using oauth2

[Examples for auth methods](https://www.drupal.org/node/910598)